# Excel convert TEXT (28th April 2017) TO DATE

Tags: excel

I have some dates in my excel spreadsheet that have th,nd,st and rd in the string so I am currently struggling to convert them to a date format of dd/mm/yyyy.

How would I be able to do this using a formula?
28th April 2017 = 28/04/2017

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a formula:

```
=--(LEFT(A1,MIN(SEARCH({"th","st","nd","rd"},A1 & "thstndrd"))-1)&" " & MID(A1,MIN(SEARCH({"th","st","nd","rd"},A1 & "thstndrd"))+3,LEN(A1)))
```

This is an array formula and needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Then format as `dd/mm/yyyy`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The text being in A1:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"th",""),"st",""),"nd",""),"rd",""))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give a try with this formula as well,

`=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1,2))),TEXT(REPLACE(A1,3,2,""),"mm/dd/yyyy"),TEXT(REPLACE(A1,2,2,""),"mm/dd/yyyy"))`

The formula finds the numeric value in first two places and formats the date accordingly. The advantage of this formula is, you can modify the `mm/dd/yyyy` format as per your needs. There would not be a necessity to change the format of the cell.

[image]