# Excel: text conversion to date format

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to convert text - Apr 7 2017 into date format on Excel spread sheet. Is there a formula that might help with it? 
I have already tried format cell into date format but this did not change the cell properties. Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel convert TEXT (28th April 2017) TO DATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870863/excel-convert-text-28th-april-2017-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=DATEVALUE(LOOKUP(LEFT(A1,3),{"Apr","Aug","Dec","Feb","Jan","Jul","Jun","Mar","May","Nov","Oct","Sep"},{4,8,12,2,1,7,6,3,5,11,10,9}) & MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","/"),4,99))
```

[image]

An alternative:

```
=DATEVALUE(TRIM(MID(A1,5,2)) & "-" & LEFT(A1,3) & "-" & RIGHT(A1,4))
```